# Forcing Yii:t to translate string in given language

Tags: php, yii, internationalization, yii2

What is the best way to force `Yii:t` to return string translated in a given language, no matter what is the current value of `Yii::$app->language`? Is there any parameter for this kind of purpose?

The only method, that I found out, is to temporarily change language and revert it back once translation is done:

```
$currentLanguage = Yii::$app->language;

if (!$translateFieldNames) {
    Yii::$app->language = 'de';
}

foreach($metaData as $name => $value) {
    $newMetaData[Yii::t('models', $name)] = $value;
}

if (!$translateFieldNames) {
    Yii::$app->language = $currentLanguage;
}
```

But that just sounds creepy to me and I'm looking, if there is a better way of doing this?

**EDIT**: I'm asking for a **Yii2** answer. I'm not using Yii 1.x anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use like this, passing language in `Yii::t()`:

```
Yii::t('base', 'Save', [], 'fr');
```

Since `Yii::t()` is a shortcut, you can also use [full method call](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/63043-forcing-yiit-to-translate-string-in-given-language/page__view__findpost__p__278267) like that:

```
Yii::$app->i18n->translate('base', 'Save', [], 'fr');
```

Comment: Works after fixes. That `null` (second to end parameter) was not required. With it, this was not working. Without it, it works like a charm. I also added reference to Yii forum, where Samdark shows alternative approach. Thanks!

Comment: I am using Yii version 1, your are v2 ?

Comment: Yes -- see question's tags, please. Anyway, I'll edit my question to not confuse others.